# XBox 360 storage device issue with Darksiders

Tags: xbox-360, darksiders

I've been playing Darksiders now for some time now and I've noticed that when I start the game, in the main menu where it says **"Press Start"**, it always triggers me to select a storage device. Why does it always ask? Is there a problem in my system, or is that just normal behavior? I never had this experience with any other game which I have played.

**System:**

XBox 360 slim 4GB with no additional storage devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This always depends on the game. Some games ask you to choose your storage device once (so it sets it as default), and never asks you again till you may want to change it from *Game Options*. Darksiders is one of the games that always ask, and its developers are the ones to blame here.

Briefly, your Xbox 360 is normal. It's a built-in feature of that game.